# In a Nodejs Sequelize model, how to obtain type information of attributes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a working model with `Postgres` and `sequelize` in `NodeJS`. Say the model is `Person` and has `name` and `age` fields. Now I want to dynamically inspect the model class and obtain information about it's attributes, like their *name* and most of all *type*.

Using `Person.attributes`
I get some information:

```
name:
{ type:
  { options: [Object],
    _binary: undefined,
    _length: 255 },
```

But as you can see the `type` object does not inform about `name` being a `varchar` or `boolean`.

Does anyone know, how to get this information with `sequelize`

Comment: Any progress here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can iterate over `rawAtributes` of Model

```
for( let key in Model.rawAttributes ){
    console.log('Field: ', key); // this is name of the field
    console.log('Type: ', Model.rawAttributes[key].type.key); // Sequelize type of field
}
```

So the example for `name` being a `Sequelize.STRING` would be

```
Field: name
Type: STRING
```

Or you can do almost the same iteration but instead using `Model.rawAttributes[key].type.key` you can use `Model.rawAttributes[key].type.toSql()`, which would generate this result

```
Field: name
Type: VARCHAR(255)
```

**EDIT**

Accessing `defaultValue` of field:

`Model.rawAttributes[field].defaultValue`

Checking if field allows `NULL` values:

`Model.rawAttributes[field].allowNull`

Comment: The author emphasized in his question that he wants to get it dynamically. If I'm not mistaken, this is a static approach.

Comment: He also asked about *how to get this information with sequelize*. Just let him choose the way that fits his needs most, ok?

Comment: I believe the most valuable thing is to be able to automatically detect when your static model becomes out of date, and needs to be refreshed.

Comment: I'm satisfied. Thank you very much. Next problem in line: How to get default values and if a column is NULLable?

Comment: I have edited the answer to show how to access `defaultValue` and `allowNull` of field

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for native type information, it seems.

I'm not familiar with Sequelize, except I know it uses `node-postgres` driver underneath, which automatically provides the type information with every query that you make.

Below is a simple example of **dynamically** getting type details for `any_table`, using [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise):

```
var pgp = require('pg-promise')(/*initialization options*/);
var db = pgp(/*connection details*/);

db.result('SELECT * FROM any_table LIMIT 0', [], a => a.fields)
    .then(fields => {
        // complete details for each column 
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // an error occurred
    });
```

There are several fields available for each column there, including `name` and `dataTypeID` that you are looking for ;)

**As an update**, following the answer that does use Sequelize for it...

The difference is that here we get direct raw values as they are provided by PostgreSQL, so `dataTypeID` is raw type Id exactly as PostgreSQL supports it, while `TYPE: STRING` is an interpreted type as implemented by Sequelize. Also, we are getting the type details dynamically here, versus statically in that Sequelize example.

Answer (score 0):

item.rawAttributes[key].type.key === this.DataTypes.JSONB.key;
@piotrbienias Is above comparison valid ?
(Sorry for writing here as I can't add comments)

Comment: You should use comments. Remove your posting pls